# JQuery Load not executed with redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am trying to record an answer to a database through a page that I load in the background (to avoid reloading the whole page). After this has been recorded, I would like to redirect the user to a new page.

I have the following JQuery:

```
       $("#ATrue").click(function(){
         $("#ranswer").load("RecAnswer.asp?a=1&oid=<%=vArr(5)%>");
         $('#reply').fadeOut('slow');
         $('#ranswer, #next').fadeIn('slow');
         $(location).attr("href",rldurl);
       });
```

With the code as above, the recording of the answer (first line)

```
         $("#ranswer").load("RecAnswer.asp?a=1&oid=<%=vArr(5)%>");
```

is not stored into the database, but I am redirected to the new page. If I take out the last line

```
         $(location).attr("href",rldurl);
```

then the above first line is fired and the reply is recorded correctly into the database. How do I have to add the redirect to only execute once the reply has been recorded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting reloads the page, and cancels any scripts that were in progress. You need to wait for the load to be done before redirecting.

```
   $("#ATrue").click(function(){
     $("#ranswer").load("RecAnswer.asp?a=1&oid=<%=vArr(5)%>", function() {
        location.href = rldurl;
     });
     $('#reply').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#ranswer, #next').fadeIn('slow');

   });
```

I don't know why you're using `.load()`, though. The purpose of that is to display the response in the `answer` DIV, but the user will never see it because you'll immediately redirect. Maybe you should be using `$.get` instead?

Comment: nevermind. I've just never seen `.attr` used on `window.location` before, threw me off.

Comment: Yeah, I find it strange, too.

Comment: But confusing to use such a non-idiom. I changed it to the normal syntax in my answer.